# unable to create a new issue through jira python rest api

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

```
            from jira.client import JIRA
            from jira.exceptions import JIRAError
            from jira.resources import Attachment, Comment,
        import time
        import types
      from sets import Set
      import xlrd
      import sys, getopt
      import getpass

       sel_server = 'https://dkbdkb7qja.ww007.net/'
       sel_user = "karthikeyan@xxxxxx.com"
        password = getpass.getpass()
        password:
         jira = JIRA(basic_auth=(sel_user, password), options={'server':   sel_server, 'verify': False})

   issue = jira.issue("EHSTRACKER-54")

    new_issue = jira.create_issue(project={"key":"EHSTRACKER"},

   summary = "New issue from jira-python",

  description= "Look into this one",

  customfield_13401= "karthi",

 customfield_13403={"value":"low"},

 customfield_13404={"value":"Other"},

 priority={"name":"Minor"},

 issuetype={"name":"EHS"})

 i'm getting the following below error
=====================================
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 8, in 
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jira_python-0.16-py2.7.egg\jira\client.py", line 485, in create_issue
    raise_on_error(r)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jira_python-0.16-py2.7.egg\jira\exceptions.py", line 47, in raise_on_error
    raise JIRAError(r.status_code, error, r.url)
jira.exceptions.JIRAError: HTTP 400: "Option id 'null' is not valid"

Can any one tell what is this error and how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

customfield_13403={"value":"low"}, -- > for this custom field i have provided first character value in "Lower case" for custom field type 'Select List' value is Case senetive "Low".i have provided customfield_13403={"value":"Low"}. for this its works for me.